# Javascript cannot display none for id

Tags: javascript

I wanna display none on this id (' + gridId + '_blankTop) but not work.
Why this still display?

My code below:

```
    if (searchRecord(gridId,'blankTop')){
        html += '<img id="' + gridId + '_blankTop"   src="./img/blank.png" height=40px width="90%"  style="display:block">';
    } else {
        html += '<img id="' + gridId + '_blankTop"   src="./img/blank.png" height=40px width="90%"  style="display:none" >';
    }

    document.body.innerHTML += html ;
    for(b=0; b<Object.keys(memberList.member).length; b++){

            var num = Object.keys(memberList.member)[b];
            var memberData = memberList["member"][num];
            var leave = memberData.split(",");

            if(d2 == num){
                document.getElementById('' + gridId + '_blankTop').style.display = 'none';
                html +='<div style="padding-left:16px; display:none;" id="' + num + '_amLeave"><span style="font-size:1.3em" id="' + gridId + '_Leave"  >AM-' + leave[0] +' <br/></span></div>';
            }
        }
```

Comment: Make sure you have that element in DOM

Comment: This error *always* means the element you think is in the DOM actually isn't. Often it's due to code being run before the DOM has loaded, or before the elements in question have been injected.